# How to use double quotes when assigning variables?

Tags: bash, variables, whitespace, double-quotes

There's a bash file with something like this:

```sh
FOO=${BAR:-"/some/path/with/$VAR/in/it"}
```

Are those double quotes necessary? Based on the following test, I'd say no, and that no quote at all is needed in the above assignment. In fact, it's the user of that variable that needs to expand it within double quotes to avoid wrong splitting.

```sh
touch 'some file'  # create a file
VAR='some file'    # create a variable for that file name
FOO=${BAR:-$VAR}   # use it with the syntax above, but no quotes
ls -l "$FOO"       # the file does exist (here we do need double quotes)
ls -l $FOO         # without quotes it fails searching for files `some` and `file`
rm 'some file'     # remove temporary file
```

Am I correct? Or there's something more?

Comment: You are right in the fact, that this particular case does not need quoting - https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F, as it falls into the category of _simple_ assignment mentioned in the link

Comment: @Inian, the link, if I understood what I've read, explains why the quotes around the whole RHS are not needed. How do I know that implies that no quotes are needed _within_ it, as happens to be the case in the first snippet in my question?

Comment: Always use double-quotes. Saving a few keystrokes’ worth of time will never outweigh the future debugging all-nighter, bound to come once scripts untouched for years start crashing due to special path characters. Been there, done that: It’s **not** worth it, ever. As for the original question, I would quote it like `FOO="${BAR:-"/some/path/with/${VAR}/in/it"}"` of maybe `FOO="${BAR:-/some/path/with/"$VAR"/in/it}"`; the details are a matter of taste and the script’s conventions. In any case, the goal is to *never* expand unknown data (e.g. variable / command expansions) unquoted.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, this looks a lot like _"let's put `;` after the `}` of a function in C++ because why not?"_

Comment: @Enlico No, it does *not* look that way at all. Let me give you a hint: In what way does a `;` after a `}` in C++ protect you against path names containing (e.g.) spaces that may appear in the future? There. That was the point. Also, analogies involving C(++) and Bash are mostly flawed.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, _Always use double-quotes (even when they are not stricly needed)_ ≈ _always put `;` after `}` (even when it closes a function)_.

Comment: @Enlico Again: There is no such equality. You do not seem to grasp the difference between an *equivalent* change to C++ code (which does not change the program’s behavior) and a *non-equivalent* change to Bash code (which *does* change the script’s behavior, dependinng on input data and/or path names). Indeed, a useless semicolon in C++ has no impact at all. By contrast, a useful (and often *necessary*) pair of double-quotes in Bash has a *big* impact on the script’s (mis)behavior in face of inputs that may undergo undesired tokenization. Double-quotes make scripts safe(r) and easier to reuse.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, are you saying you have an example of `foo=${bar:-stuff}` where some double quote is needed somewhere in `stuff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are those double quotes necessary?

Not in this case, no.

> Am I correct?

Yes. And it's *always* the user of the variable that has to quote it - field splitting is run *when expanding* the variable, so when using it it has to be quoted.

There are exceptions, like `case $var in` and `somevar1=$somevar2` - contexts which do not run field splitting, so like do not require quoting. But anyway, quotes do not hurt in such cases and can be used anyway.

> Or there's something more?

From [POSIX shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01):

> 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion
>
> In addition, a parameter expansion can be modified by using one of the following formats. In each case that a value of word is needed (based on the state of parameter, as described below), word shall be subjected to **tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion**.
>
> ${parameter:-word}

Because [field splitting expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) is not run over `word` inside `${parameter:-word}`, indeed, quoting doesn't do much.

Comment: Answer accepted, but thinking about it, I need some clarification. When you write that `var=$var` is an exception, are you referring generally to `var=$other_var` or precisely to self-assignment (which I guess should result in a no-op)? Also, your first sentence _Use them around the stuff to be assigned on the right side of `=`_ seems to be contraddicted a bit by the conclusion that `"` are not needed. Could you clarify?

Comment: `are you referring generally` Yes ;) even `var=$var1$var2--$var3`. `Could you clarify?` I am sorry, I am very literal. The question is "How to  use..." so I try to answer "How to use..." not "when to use"... Maybe this part is better removed, it serves no purpouse.

Comment: So the logic was this? "How to use double quotes when assigning variables?" -> "(If you want to use them) Use them around the stuff to be assigned on the right side of `=`."